# Rename After Copy - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use `powershell` to copy one type of file (.xlsx) from one folder to another.

Once the copy is completed, I would like the extension on the original file to be changed. (.xlsx to .cmp)

I have the copy part down (below) but I am lost when it comes to the **rename**.  Can you guys please help.  I am a PS noob!  Thank you.

```
$src = "C:\Users\x\Documents\Test1"
$dst = "C:\Users\x\Documents\Test2"

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "*.xlsx" | Move-Item -Destination $dst -Force
```

Comment: `Move <> Copy`! Move is synonymous with "cut and paste" whereas Copy is "copy and paste"

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$src = "C:\Users\x\Documents\Test1"
$dst = "C:\Users\x\Documents\Test2"

Get-ChildItem $src -Filter "*.xlsx" | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_ -Destination $dst 
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.Name -Replace '.xlsx','.cmp')
}
```

Uses a `ForEach-Object` loop to go through each item in the `$src` folder. Then for each item (represented inside the loop as `$_`) we use `Copy-Item` to copy it to the destination Then use Rename-Item with a `-Replace` to change the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you'll have to iterate over your files to be able to perform this rename.

```
# Set-up variables
$sourcePath = "C:\temp"
$sourceExtension = "txt"
$destinationPath = "C:\temp2"
$destinationExtension = "cmp"

# Grab the list of files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter "*.$sourceExtension"

# Loop over the files
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Construct the new file name
    $newFileName = (Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath $file.BaseName) + ".$destinationExtension"

    Write-Output "New File Name = $newFileName"

    # Move the file to the new destination with its new name!
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $newFileName
}
```

Note: `BaseName` = filename *without* extension